# Java question (calling methods with parameters) using UnboundID LDAP SDK api

Tags: java, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I'm using UnboundID LDAP SDK for my LDAP server. 
I made a method for connecting.

```
public static LDAPConnection connectSDK(String ip, Integer port, String id, String pw) throws LDAPException    {

    LDAPConnection ldap = new LDAPConnection(ip,port,id,pw);
    System.out.println("success");  
    return ldap;

}
```

In my main method, I call this methods with parameters, and it works fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws LDAPException {

    connectSDK("192.168.0.60",389,"******","*****");

}
```

I wanted to go further. I made a method to search data using a filter.

```
public static void searchSDK(String filter) throws LDAPException {

    LDAPConnection ldap = connectSDK(); 

/* Before calling a method with parameter, I used to connect with this,
 and use 'ldap' variable to put search results. 
Now, I am using a method with parameters. 
I don't know what to do with 'ldap' variable. 
If I delete it, 'SearchRequest' doesn't run.  
Also how can I continue to use the connection from connectSDK method? */

    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("c=kr",SearchScope.SUB,filter);
    SearchResult searchResult = ldap.search(searchRequest);
    System.out.println(searchResult);

}
```

Ultimately, I want to call two of these methods in my main like below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws LDAPException {
    //connect
    connectSDK("192.168.0.60",389,"*****","******");
    //search using a filter 
    searchSDK("hotdog");
}
```

I want advice in my searchSDK()  methods.
 *1) how to use the session connectSDK method created
 *2) how to handle 'ldap' variable.
 *3) ldap.close()  I want to close a session after, but this method wouldn't work. Is there any other way?

Comment: Put the `ldap.close` into a `finally` block or use `try-with-resources` if `LDAPConnection` has the `AutoCloseable` interface

Comment: @Scary Wombat How can I pass LDAPConnection ldap from connectSDK  to searchSDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method in your code `LDAPConnection ldap = connectSDK();` As `connectSDK(String ip, Integer port, String id, String pw)` returns a `LDAPConnection` then pass this as a parameter into `searchSDK` and remove `connectSDK()` from it.

Modify the code as

```
public static void searchSDK(String filter, LDAPConnection ldap) throws LDAPException {

    // LDAPConnection ldap = connectSDK(); 
....
}
```

So your main would look like

```
LDAPConnection ldap = connectSDK("192.168.0.60",389,"*****","******");
//search using a filter 
searchSDK("hotdog", ldap);
```

Comment: thank you. How can I call this method in my main?   searchSDK("hotdog", ?);